# How do I sort the list from database automatically according to the language?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How do I sort the list from database automatically according to the language in Java or SQL?
List listed according to the user's language.

Comment: How can you sort database-entries by language? Aren't the values in the db the same no matter which language you have in your application?

Comment: This question is not directly related with JSF nor JSF 2. Just use an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL statement or use `Collections#sort` in Java side after retrieving the list form your database. Take into account that in this scenario, JSF will act as a HTML generator, nothing more.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @OblTobl: think of a table that contains e.g. product names in different languages (english, german, french)

Comment: yes, thats clear, but then you have some flag or something that identifies the language, no?

Comment: @Obl: That's called collation. This keyword should give you clues in both SQL and Java related documentations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the way Oracle sorts data by changing the `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP` parameter for your session.

If you want to retrieve say french data, you can use the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = Linguistic;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = XFrench_AI;

select *
from my_table
where language_code = 'fr'
order by some_column;
```

Consequently if you want to retrieve german data, you use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = Linguistic;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = XGerman_CI;

select *
from my_table
where language_code = 'de'
order by some_column;
```

More details can be found in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm